# How To Retrieve Checkedlistbox Value From Database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, checkedlistbox

I need to fetch data from datagridview to checkedlistbox while i click on modify button in C#.

data will be already stored in database during insert operation, while updating i need to fetch the data from database to checkedlistbox, and the data should be checked.

Data from database should compare with data in checkedlistbox, if both equals then it should be checked.

```
string category = dgEntry.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
string[] strCat = category.Split(',');
int length = strCat.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++)
{
    string fetch = strCat[i];
    foreach (object item in clbEntry_IndividualItems.Items)
    {
        DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;
        if (row[0].ToString() == strCat[i].ToString())
        {
            clbEntry_IndividualItems.SetItemChecked(i, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: what is the result you get by your code?

Comment: Sir, its fetching data from database and the problem is while comparing, none of the values in checkedlistbox is checked

Comment: Sir, now first data in checkedlistbox is checked, while click on modify

Comment: dose it work dear @abelS ?

Comment: No sir, still its the same

Answer (score 0):

if your first check is true (as your comment) then you can add 2nd loop to check all:

```
  string category = dgEntry.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
    string[] strCat = category.Split(',');
    int length = strCat.Length;
    int _lenghth =clbEntry_IndividualItems.Items.count();
    for (int j=0, j<_lenghth ,j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++)
    {
        string fetch = strCat[i];
        foreach (object item in clbEntry_IndividualItems.Items)
        {
            DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;
            if (row[j].ToString() == strCat[i].ToString())
            {
                clbEntry_IndividualItems.SetItemChecked(i, true);
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but still its not getting exact value, only the top value is checked